# how can I get which class has been passed to method

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class with 9 different properties of which each one is a class

```
public class Vehicles
{
  Car car; //class
  Train train;  //class
  Plane plane; //class
}
```

I pass this Vehicle object to a method

for example

```
var Vehicles = new Vehicles();
Vehicles.Car = new Car()
Object1.WorkOutTransport(vehicle)
```

what I need to do in Object1 is workout which 'vehicle' has been instantiated without using a switch statement and checking if the others are null or not

this is NOT a 'homework question'...I have simplified it to illustrate problem only

the actual vehicles class have 9 possible classes that could be instantiated

Comment: Do `Car`, `Train`, `Plane`, etc have a common parent class?

Comment: I feel like this is a place for an interface

Comment: yes have common 'Vehicle' parent

Comment: I think @Blorgbeard meant, do they all inherit the same base class?

Comment: @kurasa What's the need for having one property for each vehicle type?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend rethinking your design.

Why not have all of your vehicle types implement a common interface `IVehicle`, then have your `Vehicles` class have one property named `Vehicle`.

You'll only have one property to worry about.

```
public Interface IVehicle 
{
    ... //Properties Common to all vehicles
}

public class Car : IVehicle
{
    ... //Properties to implement IVehicle
    ... //Properties specific to Car
}

public class Vehicles
{
    public IVehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}

var vehicles = new Vehicles();
vehicles.Vehicle = new Car();
... //Do whatever else you need to do.
```

Comment: If the get/set are Public properties with no logic behind them, they should be variables.

Comment: just curious, why should they be variables?

Comment: I agree. @OverMars what is your reasoning for that?

Comment: I would say exactly the opposite.  Using fields instead of properties would remove the ability to use them in situations you may like.  Such as serialization and databinding in asp.net

Comment: If the property has no logic behind its getter/setter and both are public, then why make a pointer to a variable when all you want is the variable. @JefferyKhan is right, if you know why your using them, they are great. Its just that I have seen many cases where properties serve no real purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only one will be non-null, you can do this:

```
Vehicle instance = vehicle.Car ?? vehicle.Train ?? vehicle.Plane;
```

But if you want to do anything useful with your `instance` you are left having to check `typeof(instance)` and casting it to the right class..

You might want to consider only having one property :

```
public class Vehicles
{
    public Vehicle VehicleInstance {get; set;}
}
```

And move functionality around so that your WorkOutTransport method can act on a `Vehicle` instance instead of caring which subclass it has. Use `virtual` or `abstract` methods in the `Vehicle` class, and `override` them in the subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

If you use different properties, not checking which is null or not can't be avoided. I suggest a base class with a property identifying the type or override the `ToString` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could force the interface inheritors to specify their type:

```
enum VehicleType
{
    Passenger,
    Truck,
    // Etc...
}

public Interface IVehicle 
{
    VehicleType Type { get; }
    ... // Properties Common to all vehicles
}

public sealed class Truck : IVehicle
{
    // ... class stuff.

    // IVehicle implementation.
    public VehicleType Type { get { return VehicleType.Truck; } }
}
```

This will allow you to not to look over each class, but to know exactly to what type to cast.

```
IVehicle vehicle = GetVehicle();

switch (vehicle.Type)
    case (VehicleType.Truck)
    {
        // Do whatever you need with an instance.
        Truck truck = (Truck)vehicle;
        break;
    }
    // ... Etc
```

You any aother appoarch except for the `switch`.